# How to flatten a nested NSArray using RXCollections

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, collections

My typical pattern for flattening an NSArray containing arrays would be something like:

```
NSMutableArray *flattenedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSArray *innerObjects in arrayToFlatten) {
    [flattenedArray addObjectsFromArray:innerObjects];
}
```

(or I'd use the @unionOfArrays KVC collection operator).

What would be the best equivalent using RXCollections? I have:

```
NSArray *flattenedArray = RXConstructArray(RXFold(arrayToFlatten, [NSMutableArray array], ^id(id memo, id each,
    bool *stop) {
    NSMutableArray *accumulator = memo;
    [accumulator addObjectsFromArray:each];
    return accumulator;
}));
```

But the use of the NSMutableArray accumulator smells incongruous to me.

---

I've left the original above so as not to make nonsense of Rob's answer, but the (thus far) improved version is:

```
NSArray *flattenedArray = RXFold(arrayToFlatten, [NSMutableArray array], ^id(NSMutableArray *accumulator, NSArray *array,
    bool *stop) {
    [accumulator addObjectsFromArray:array];
    return accumulator;
});
```

Comment: This does seem to match the canonical flattening operations in most functional languages `foldr (++) [] arrayToFlatten`

Comment: OK. A new foray for me into map/filter/reduce. I was expecting it to be less verbose and/or more declarative than the imperative loopy approach. Seems neither.

Comment: Well, that's what happens when you try to jam a functional paradigm into an imperative language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using this, or any other abstraction, I find it helps me to think about the structure of the process. Semantically, flattening an array of arrays into a single array is a fold; so this code implements that pretty directly. (Aside: Did you know you can just type the memo as `NSMutableArray *` rather than `id`, instead of doing that temporary assignment? Covariance for the win!)

On the other hand, if you care more about traversing the objects in the nested arrays in sequence than about the resultant array, then what you really want is a traversal composed of the traversals of each contained array.

You can fold it into an array with `RXConstructArray()` at that point, but you have a purely lazy process if you don’t need to produce a final array value.

Two notes about this:

1. `RXConstructArray()` returns a lazily-populated array, similar to how Core Data fetches work with `fetchBatchSize` set.
2. Your use of `RXFold()` doesn’t actually require `RXConstructArray()`, because it’s returning the memo as produced by its final evaluation of the block, not a traversal. In technical details, this is because `RXFold()` evaluates strictly, not lazily; a lazy fold function in ObjC sounds like a fun project, though!

Comment: Thank you. Given RXFold() evaluates strictly, I assume you have an alternative to using it in mind when you suggest using traversals to provide a lazy implementation of flattening? Any hints? I don't see an obvious alternative (but I'm not practiced in the use of higher-order functions).

Comment: (an aside: I started using temp variables to type block arguments after finding varying block parameter names made the various Cocoa collection enumeration methods less readable as whole phrases, at a glance. But at least in this context I think you're right, and it's a bad tradeoff).

Comment: I realise btw that I can create a traversal from an array using RXFilter with RXAcceptFilterBlock, but I don't know how to flatten without using a fold.

Comment: I was actually thinking of implementing a traversal—which is almost certainly *not* a reasonable, practical thing to do. I’m currently looking at this as a flaw in the traversal APIs, that it isn’t convenient to construct a traversal for this sort of task without implementing the `RXTraversal` protocol.

Comment: (Additionally, I think the more appropriate way to get a traversal for an array of objects would be to use `RXTraversalWithEnumeration()`.)

Comment: At any rate, the idea was to make a traversal composed of the traversals of the child arrays.

Comment: So the real question is: do you need the array, or do you need to do things with the elements of the child arrays in sequence? The former is a case for the fold. The latter *might* be a case for a traversal, if the API were better adapted for the challenge. I shall have to think about this.

Comment: Certainly the latter in the specific case I had in mind. Although that case prompted the question, however, my real intent was to ask (as a beginner to using this stuff) whether my implementation was silly, or obviously unidiomatic. I'll mark the question as answered.

Comment: If I follow you correctly, in the absence of either a lazy fold, or convenient way to obtain traversals of collection items that are themselves collections, RXCollections doesn't offer a means of lazy evaluation in this kind of case. If so, that would be worth you thinking about. I wonder if there's a good way of generalising what 'this kind of case' is?

Comment: It’s definitely worth some thought! There’s definitely a generalization; I mean, generators exist to handle this sort of case in Python (and indeed in RXCollections), but since generators are also coroutines you have somewhat more headroom there. The key to a lazy fold is that the result can be lazily evaluated (folding on demand). In this case since it’s producing an array, we know that, but the code does not. In the case of e.g. a sum, it can’t be (although it could maybe be a lazy proxy for the result, e.g. a promise). Bears more thought, definitely…